# Oracle Concurrent Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, concurrency, sql-insert

We have simple case like

```
 Create table t1 (c1 number primary);
```

session1:

```
insert into t1 values (1); -- **session1 does not commit transaction**
```

session2:

```
insert into t1 values (2);
```

Would session2 hang/wait for session1 to commit/rollback transaction or not, as we are inserting different values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're inserting different values, the legality of session 2's insert is independent on session 1 - therefore it will not hang, it will just succeed (or fail with ORA-00001 if that value already exists in the table for some reason).

The only case where a session hangs in such a usecase is if Oracle cannot determine if the insert value will violate a constraint or not. E.g., if both sessions inserted the same value, the first will succeed and the second will hang. If the first session commits, the second will fail with an ORA-00001 error. If the first one rollbacks, the second will succeed.

Comment: thanks, in case both sessions inserted the same value, then first will succeed, is there ways that 2nd session update that row instead of throwing error. Like we have another column for timestamp & want that 2nd session instead of throwing error simple update the timestamp column ?